# Form authentication in api not working after migrating client app to azure authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, openid, forms-authentication

I have two applications API and client. The two were working fine when they both used Forms authentication with machine key. After migrating the client app to azure authentication using OpenId and OWIN everything is fine with client, users can login with no issues to client.

The issue is when the client now tries to make call to API I get a 401 error.

I tried to generate forms authentication cookie in my client and add that to response. I can see that cookie is there but I still get a 401 from the API.

Comment: If your client app is using OpenIDConnect, you have to set OpenIDConnect also for API to make it work. Forms are using cookies, but OpenIDConnect uses tokens. Those are two different concepts. Take a look at this sample => https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API

Comment: Thanks man! I got it to work with your suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, confirm the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot combine OpenIdConnect on client side and Forms authentication on server side.

You have to set both, client and server, to use same authentication. If you went for OpenIdConnect on client, you need to set OpenIdConnect on server side too.

There is a sample on GitHub that may help you to understand how to do it.

[How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using the Microsoft identity platform (formerly Azure Active Directory for developers)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API)